# After my input, my datas are receive as null

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i'm creating a form to a simple study, but is not working correctly, my form sends the values but my backend flask show with null, i tested the backend with insomnia it is okay, help please

My HTML,JS

```
 <form name="myForm" method="POST">
            <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname"></p>

            <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname"></p>

            <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="create_send_Json()">
 </form>

        <script>
            function create_send_Json() {

                // get name
                var fname = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
                var lname = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;

                // make JSON
                data = { "fname": fname, "lname": lname };
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

                // Send data
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = 'http://localhost:5000/contact';

                xhr.open("POST", url);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                console.log(jsonData);
                xhr.send(jsonData);


                return false;
            }
   </script>
```

My Flask

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        print (data)
        return jsonify(data)


    else:
        return render_template('contact.html')
```

Comment: so you've confirmed that the POST data in the browser doesn't send null? can I suggest `onclick="return create_send_Json()"` to prevent the form from submitting since you do an XHR in the submit - perhaps that's somehow messing with the request

Comment: regardless ... put `onclick="return create_send_Json()"` - i.e. add the return there as well